# Add Status Bar Under Dynamically Sized Creature

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a generic "creature" prefab in my game.  When I instantiate an instance of the prefab into the scene, I assign the creature's type (dragon, goblin, etc.).  Then the creature's `Creature` script dynamically loads its animator, based on what type of creature it is.  I do that in `Awake`.  In `Start`, I want to create a health bar (from a prefab) positioned underneath the creature.  I'm using `GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().bounds.extents` to determine the size of the creature so that I can position the health bar appropriately.

If I assign a sprite to the creature's `SpriteRenderer`, this works correctly. 
 However, the problem that I'm having is that each creature is a different size so I can't assign an appropriately sized sprite to the `SpriteRenderer` in the creature prefab.  If I leave the `SpriteRenderer`'s `Sprite` property set to `None`, then `GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().bounds.extents` is of size (0, 0, 0) in `Start`, even though I have an `Animator` attached to the creature.  My assumption is that the `Animator` hasn't started animating while I'm inside of `Creature.Start`, which is causing the creature's `SpriteRenderer` to have a zero size.

Here's an except from the code that I use to create the status bar.  This code is in a script which is attached to the `Canvas` which holds the status bars.  I call it from `Creature.Start`

```
SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

GameObject statusBar = Instantiate(
   this.statusBarPrefab,
   new Vector3(0, 0, 0),
   this.transform.rotation) as GameObject;
this.statusBars.Add(statusBar);

RectTransform rectTransform = statusBar.transform.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
statusBar.transform.SetParent(this.transform, false);
statusBar.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0);

// Here is where the problem is.  spriteRenderer.bounds.extents is all zeros
float y = -spriteRenderer.bounds.extents.y - (this.statusBars.Count * (rectTransform.rect.height / 2f) * 1.5f);

// TranslateY is an extension method I made which translates the vector
statusBar.transform.position = statusBar.transform.position.TranslateY(y);
```

How should I solve this?  I thought a solution would be to get the size of the creature's first animation frame, but I can't find a way to do that.  Is there another way around this issue?

Comment: You said that each creature has a different size, can you elaborate a little more? Are the sizes defined by the scale of the object, or the resolution of the sprite?

Comment: Already had some problems with Unity components only starting to behave "correctly" after the `Start` initialization has been completed. One dirt way to solve it is to set a bool to `false` in `Start()` and check if it's `false` in `Update()`: if it is, do what you have to do and set it to `true` (this way it will only happen once during the first frame).

Comment: @StevenCoull The sizes are defined by the resolution of the sprite.

Comment: I created a solution by adding a script which dynamically loads an image into the `SpriteRenderer` during its `Awake` (based on the appropriate creature type), but I'm still curious if there's a built-in way to solve this, or if trying to get an animated object's size is something that I'm fundamentally doing incorrectly.